# block of coding running twice

Tags: flutter, dart

So am having a scroll listener to get more data now the problem is that when the listener calls the function for more data then am having 4 if conditions but the function is running the if condition twice i don't understand the logic behind it.

MyCode:-

```
void _scrollListener()async{
    if (!loading) {
      if (scrollController.position.pixels == scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        setState(() => load = true);
        await clearEmptyDocs();
        getMoreData();
      }
    }
  }

getMoreData()async
  {
    var quicks;
    var posts;
    if(publicPostsDocuments.isNotEmpty)
    {
      print('1\n\n\n\n');
      posts=await getPublicPosts();
    }
    if(publicQuicksDocuments.isNotEmpty)
    {
      print('2\n\n\n\n');
      quicks=await getPublicQuicks();
    }
    if(publicPostsDocuments.isEmpty)
    {
      print('3\n\n\n\n');
      posts=await getPublicDocuments();
    }
    if(publicQuicksDocuments.isEmpty)
    {
      print('4\n\n\n\n');
      quicks=await getPublicDocumentsForQuicks();
    }
    setState(() {
      load=false;
    });
  }
```

Here am having four lists and based on them am having if blocks so when lists are not empty then it should simply print 1 and 2 and then exit but it is printing 1,2,1,2 i.e. first 2 if blocks are running twice.

Comment: If you add more debug, could you check if the scroll listener is called multiple times?

Comment: could u tell how can i check that is it being called multiple times or not. I have added the listener only once so i dont think so

Comment: By adding debug in _scrollListener to see if you get multiple events.